# convert from one timezone to another in java

Tags: java

I have a datetime in UTC timezone in UTC format ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z').  Is there an easy way (without using joda) to convert it into another timezone (PDT,EST etc) in a certain/or standard (to that timezone) date format?

Thanks

Comment: what's the issue with joda?

Comment: I dont want to add one more dependency in my pom - have to go through a lot of process to do that!

Comment: I suggested date4j but based on your comment, you just want a way of doing this simply using core java (unless I misunderstood)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String formatInTimezone(String utcDateString, String intendedTimeZone) {
    SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date theDate = utcFormat.parse(utcDateString);

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z");
    outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(intendedTimeZone));
    return outputFormat.format(theDate);
}
```

Comment: looks good.  Gonna try it!
ps: Are you the same David Wallace from "The Office" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into using date4j instead of joda (though I would prefer joda unless there were clear reasons not to use it).

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now(someTimeZone);
dt.changeTimeZone(fromOneTimeZone, toAnotherTimeZone);
```

Perhaps something like this:

```
DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
  System.out.println(formatter.format(instance2.getTime()))
```

Comment: can I not do it in jata.util.Date?

Comment: you may wish to look into offsets as well based on your requirement if you wish to go that route.  In most cases, its not useful to try to implement that logic yourself.

Comment: Gonna try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar object and set it time based on the local instead of germany use EST and PDT

```
Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    localTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
    localTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    localTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

int hour = localTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = localTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = localTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


// Print the local time
System.out.printf("Local time  : %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);


// Create a calendar object for representing a Germany time zone. Then we
// wet the time of the calendar with the value of the local time

Calendar germanyTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Germany"));
germanyTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
hour = germanyTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
minute = germanyTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
second = germanyTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    // Print the local time in Germany time zone
    System.out.printf("Germany time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);
```